# Generic process usage in uDeploy

Tags: urbancode, udeploy

How to find the deployment history or generic process usage of each process in uDeploy? I need to cleanup the unwanted generic processes from UI.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any direct option, we usually will check if any generic process is not used for 6 months and clean it up